# How do I stop my recliner from scratching wood floor

Tags: hardwood-floor, furniture

I have hardwood floors and recently purchased a recliner.  The recliner slides around on the hardwood floor.  Is there a product that will stop the recliner from sliding and more importantly stop it from scratching the floor?

Also, the bottom of the recliner is a big disc approximately 24" in diameter.

Comment: Have you considered a rug?  Worked great in a baby room for us.

Comment: it's in an odd spot for a rug and it would be next to another rug.  I suppose I could just get a small piece of carpet to put under there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A [rug pad](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00IAVY52U) might work well.  They can be purchased at most home stores, or online. They're cheap, and can usually be trimmed easily into any shape/size.

[image]

They're designed to prevent rugs from slipping, so should also prevent your chair from sliding around.

Comment: I have this readily available.  Assuming there are no better solutions at menards I'll give this a shot.

Answer (score 3):

Does the recliner have distinct "feet" under the disk?

If so, some rubber floor protecting pads under those feet should stop the scratches and the sliding:

[image]

*([this one](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0123KWF4S) is just a representative sample, they come in many shapes, sizes, and materials)*

If the entire disk contacts the floor, then how about just putting a carpet under it (with a non-slip pad under the carpet)

Comment: I'll swing by menards and see if they have anything.  The only issue I could foresee is that there is not "feet" because it's a large disk

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar situation in my front room.  I found [silicone sheets](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001EW808W) at big box and cut them into strips.  Then super glued them to recliner bottom.  They have been on there for 2 years with no issues.  Chairs don't slide, no scratches, don't need a rug.

Comment: very interesting!

Answer (score 0):

Put the recliner on a nice big circular rug.